# Two GA4 accounts, two different interfaces

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-4

I am confused as to why two GA4 accounts have different interfaces. Specifically, one has a "Business Objectives" section but the other has a "Life cycle" section.
Can anyone explain the difference? See these screenshots.

[image]

[image]